# future promises R shiny renderplotly pool

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny, promise, future

I am trying to use futures and promises in order to speed up the time it takes for multiple people to query an SQLite database. this is my first venture with futures and promises and I am definitely struggling a bit. any info / direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(promises)
library(future)

plan(multisession)

poolfinderdatabase <- dbPool(drv = SQLite(), dbname = "NewDB")


output$poolfinderTS <- renderPlotly({

future({tbl(poolfinderdatabase, "NewDB")%>%
filter( CPN %in% local(input$Coupon1),Story %in% local(input$PoolStories1), Coll %in% 
 local(input$Agency1),WALA >= local(input$wala_sliders[1]) & WALA<= local(input$wala_sliders[2]), 
 Current.Face >= 5000000)%>%
 collect()%>%
mutate(Coll = gsub("FGLMC", "FNCL",Coll))%>%
group_by(Date,CPN,Story,Coll)%>%
summarize(Median = median(get(input$Y1),na.rm = TRUE))%>%
ungroup()%>%
mutate(Date =parse_date_time(x = Date, orders = c("mdy","ymd")))%>%
mutate(Product = paste(Coll," ",CPN," ",Story))})%...>%

{
TimeSeries_Chart <- ggplot(.,aes(Date,Median, group = 1,colour = Product)) 
geom_line()+
theme_minimal()+
theme_light()+
scale_color_hue(l=40, c=80)

ggplotly(TimeSeries_Chart)

}
})
```